# How are Madam Vice President and Philly Falzone's agendas related in Prison Break?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, prison-break

I'm in S01E10 of Prison Break, so far I see that Madam Vice President does not want Lincoln Burrows to be exonerated. Philly Falzone wants Fibonacci because he got to know about the dealings of the Mafia.

1. I'm not sure I remember but has Madam Vice President ever mentioned the need to find Fibonacci before?
2. Also, in the S01E10, one of those two goons who're after Lincoln Burrows's lawyers pay Madam Vice President a visit and tells her "These guys are in on this thing now, and there's no going back". Who are "these guys" that he's talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Madam Vice President does not want Lincoln Burrows exonerated because the Company does not want it. 
Philly Falzone wants Fibonacci (who was in Witness Protection) so he couldn't testify against him in a trial.

1. No, neither the Company nor Madam Vice President had a need to find Fibonacci (they probably didn't even know who he is). Only Abruzzi and his Mafia family (including Falzone) were interested in that.
2. "these guys" refer to the Company.